# Public array not accepting values

Tags: arrays, reporting-services

I have an issue with a public array. I have worked with arrays in other languages, and the following code seems to make sense: it *should* work.

When I try to get the values of anything in either array, it comes back blank.

```vb
public dim TicketSerial(0) as String 
public dim TicketOpenedDate(0) as Date

function LoadFPRArray(ByVal LoadSerial as string, ByVal LoadTicketOpenedDate as Date) As Boolean
'Load array of ticket data into global variable (Create a hidden table to 'accomplish this, sort on date). Serial / Opened Date

Dim k as Long

k = UBound(TicketSerial)+1

Redim Preserve TicketSerial(0 to k) 
Redim Preserve TicketOpenedDate(0 to k)

TicketSerial(k) = LoadSerial
TicketOpenedDate(k) = LoadTicketOpenedDate

return true

end function
```

Comment: Did you try .. `public dim TicketSerial() as String` and `public dim TicketOpenedDate() as Date`. [Document Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716275(v=vs.60).aspx). Also did you check what variable `k` holds after `k= UBound(TicketSerial)+1`?

Comment: You might also try `TicketSerial(k-1) = LoadSerial`. As I can remember you define your array but it's zero based when reference.

Comment: I did try () first with the same results.  I figured because nothing was in the array that was causing the issue so i tried dim with 1 element.  I'll debug the value of ķ tomorrow and post back the results.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I changed the function to return k. When i preview the report, every row increments by one, but the next page it resets to 1 again. If i export the report, it iterates as expected for each row from 1 to 900 (the number of rows). I'm confused. This function is called from the dataset as a calculated field... what gives @Jeroen ?